# Drupal 7: Why isn't the rendered node being displayed with kpr?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks, theming

I'm following a tutorial from Drupalize.me and it says that if I add this code...

```
function mythemenameishere_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  kpr($hook);
}
```

...in the template.php file, I'm supposed to see something similar to...

```
node
node
node
block
region
```

...which shows that each individual node is  getting rendered prior to the block and region. And I do have 3 nodes of content type featured_item, and 3 nodes of content type article. But I only get...

```
block
region
```

... and NO NODES. Why is that? I'm in the homepage.

Comment: How are the nodes being outputted? Are they in a view?

Comment: Yes, I have a region, and created a view and a block. I use this in page--front.tpl.php `print render($page['featured_slider']);`

Comment: Any chance your view is set to output fields rather than rendered content? If so, that would explain why the preprocess hook for node isn't being called

Comment: Ah, if you've got `Show: Content` that's already the right setting. I've just tried it and it looks like `hook_preprocess` isn't invoked for nodes, which is contrary to what the function documentation says as far as I can tell. It might be easier to just use `hook_preprocess_node` for your purposes instead

Comment: Yes, I think it now works, it was just a matter of changing from `Show: Fields` to `Show: Content`. Please enter it as an answer and I will set it as the chosen answer. Thanks! :D